# Add data attribute to an element in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add `li` element with `data-attribute` say `data-payload`.

Here is my code.

```js
 
   btn_str += "<li onclick=\"btnClick('"+ind+"',this)\" data-payload=/book_appointment{'service_slot':'Book Appointment'}><a>"+btn.title+"</a></li>";
```

The above code works successfully except, it adds a double quote `"` between whitespace in the value side of key-value pair, like

After appending the `li` element the value of `data-payload` is looks like

```
data-payload="/book_appointment{'service_slot':'Book" appointment'}
```

In the above code snippet, you can see a double quote after Book. Why it comes after appending?
how can i resolve this?

Since when i retrieve the `data-payload` in JS i am getting upto `"/book_appointment{"service_slot":"Book` .

Comment: "The above code works successfully" - no it doesn't. The first line throws a syntax error

Comment: @Quentin I said it because of it works in my source code, the first line it just an example, the payload value coming from some other variable, that's why i created a sample variable in this question.

Comment: Provide an example that demonstrates the problem you are having, not an example which throws a completely different error.

Comment: escape doble quotes with ` \ ` ... `var payload = "/book_appointment{\"service_slot\":\"Book Appointment\"}";`

Comment: @Roy,  the quotes you mentioned is working fine, actually after appending the li element the value becomes `"Book" appointment"` . I tadd one more `"` after `Book`

Comment: You are having the same problem in the other line, so, with `\"` instead `&quot;` can solve it.

Comment: @Roy, i tried with `\` too. but no luck.

Comment: Are you sure you want to wrap the whole payload in `&quot;` ?? That seems odd when you want to just get  `/book_appointment{"service_slot":"Book Appointment"}`

Comment: Could you also explain what you intend to do with this HTML? Insert it in the document so it gets the `li` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a pain to escape quotes both for JavaScript string literals (`\"`) and for HTML properties (`&quot;`).

The `jquery` tag in your question suggest that you use jQuery, and then you have a tool at your hands with which you can easily avoid this quote-escaping-hell.
Build your `li` element with jQuery, and use the `click` method to bind the click handler instead of using an `onclick` HTML attribute.

By passing an object literal to `JSON.stringify` you further ensure that the object notation is parsed before actually running that code, which safeguards against JSON syntax mistakes.

Demo:

```js
var $li = $("<li>").attr("data-payload", 
    "/book_appointment" + JSON.stringify({service_slot: "Book appointment"})
).append($("<a>").text("Book Appointment"))
.click(function () { btnClick("payload0", this) });

$("#mylist").append($li);

function btnClick(action, li) {
    console.log("action=" + action);
    console.log("text=" + $(li).text());
    console.log("data=" + $(li).data("payload"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mylist">
</ul>
```

#### If you need the HTML

I would strongly advise against building the HTML with `btn_str += .....`. Just create all the elements and use the jQuery `append` method to insert them in the document.

But if you still choose to go ahead with such string manipulation, then do it as follows:

```js
var $li = $("<li>").attr({
    "data-payload":
    "/book_appointment" + JSON.stringify({service_slot: "Book appointment"}),
    onclick: 'btnClick("payload0", this)'
}).append($("<a>").text("Book Appointment"));

var btn_str = $li.get(0).outerHTML;

console.log(btn_str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Running this script you can see that the HTML string corresponds to:

```
var html = '<li data-payload="/book_appointment{&quot;service_slot&quot;:&quot;Book appointment&quot;}" onclick="btnClick(&quot;payload0&quot;, this)"><a>Book Appointment</a></li>';
```

I would however not write it directly like that, as it is difficult to read and modifications would be error-prone.

Comment: i tried your solution,
`btn_str += "<li onclick=btnClick('"+ind+"',this) data-payload=/book_appointment"+JSON.stringify({service_slot:'Book Appointment'})+"><a>"+btn.title+"</a></li>";
      console.log('jsonstringfy',JSON.stringify({service_slot:'Book Appointment'}));`
in console i getting `{"service_slot":"Book Appointment"}`.
But in html same issue. Actually the quote of data attribute get closed after `book` instead of `appointment`.

Comment: My solution is *not* to do `btn_str +=`. Why do you choose to still do it via string manipulation? Anyway, check addition to answer, where I give a solution to build the HTML string correctly, even though I think you should focus on using jQuery to populate your document, not HTML strings.